# Link Referrer in HTML

Tags: html, reference, referrer, rel

I want to ask a quetion about rel property of a tag in HTML (actually, HTML5 if that will make any difference)

I'll continue with example domain names. My website is example.com. I've a link to this page at example2.com. If I give this link with something like

```
<a href="example.com" referrer="referrer.com">Click me</a>
```

will my referrer be referrer.com or example2.com? BTW is there anything possible like that code? Giving a random referrer?

2nd one, because I think subjects are similar.

- Is it possible to hide referrer URL?
- If it's, what will be shown as referrer (in statistics programs or
  browser)?

Long story short, I want to hide and/or change the referrer.

Comment: There is no `rel` property here.

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that a meta refresh does not leave a trace of a referrer `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com">` The thing here though, is getting it from an onclick (`a`) element, so you *should*, AFAIK, be able to do something like:

```
<a onclick="mask('http://www.example.com/')">Click me</a>

function mask(url) {
    var meta = document.createElement("meta");
    meta.setAttribute("http-equiv", "refresh");
    meta.setAttribute("content", "0; url=" + url);
}
```

Disclaimer: untested

Comment: Thanks for help. How can I test that? Is there a webpage shows referrer like which shows IP (for testing)

Comment: anyway I found a site and tested. Your code didn't work but gave me the idea (you already said untested so don't think I'm blaming you or something else). thanks for the code. I've used another way to att meta tag and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

In HTML5, the [link type `noreferrer` (link to W3C HTML5 **CR**)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#link-type-noreferrer) can be used:

> It indicates that no referrer information is to be leaked when following the link.
>
> If a user agent follows a link defined by an `a` or `area` element that has the `noreferrer` keyword, the user agent must not include a `Referer` (sic) HTTP header (or equivalent for other protocols) in the request.

Example use:

```html
<a href="http://example.com/" rel="noreferrer">Click me</a>
```

**Note:** This link type is not part of W3C’s Recommendations of HTML5 and HTML 5.1, but it’s part of WHATWG’s HTML Living standard: [Link type "noreferrer"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#link-type-noreferrer).