# Is there a standard HTML syntax for indicating the referring page in a URL?

Tags: html, url, refer

I want my links to some sites to indicate the page on which the link was clicked. Is there a standard HTML syntax for indicating the referring page or a standard parameter added to the URLs which is recognized by most web servers software, CMSs or log analytics software recognizes?

Comment: There's the ["canonical URL"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en).  I'm not sure how many services support it though.

Answer (score 0):

This happens on the **HTTP** level, with the [`Referer` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). While this is optional and can, of course, be controlled by the client, it’s typically sent by default.

A referrer policy allows authors to control the behavior. See [*Referrer Policy*](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/) (currently a draft).  Within **HTML**, authors can use the [`noreferrer` link type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758402/1591669) (per link), the [`referrerpolicy` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#referrer-policy-attributes) (per link), and the [`referrer` meta name](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#meta-referrer) (per document).

Popular **URL parameters**, used for analytics/tracking, are the [UTM parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters). The `utm_source` parameter provides the source, but it doesn’t (necessarily) take a URL value. See, for example, [Google’s Analytics documentation about this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en).